# Numbering equations in IguanaTex, Power point

Tags: numbering, iguanatex

I am using the IguanaTex for PowerPoint and need to add a number of equations. I have tried to use the standard expression as:

```
\begin{equation}
\end{equation}
```

But it doesn't work. All equations have the same number.

Does anyone know how I can add a number of an equation in IguanaTex/ Powerpoint?

PS In Powerpoint I am using IguanaTex only for math equations. I am looking for another method.

Comment: Welcome back to TeX.SE! When you say "it doesn't work", what exactly do you mean? Do you get an error? Or you get an equation, but without a number? Or the wrong number? Or no output at all?

Comment: @Marijn All equations have a number (1).

Answer (score 1):

Independent IguanaTex environments do not know about each others content. So a new environment will start numbering equations again from 1,2,3, etc. You can set the starting point of your equation numbering by using the following line in the preamble.

`\setcounter{equation}{#}`

where # is your desired number.